# send email based on checkbox selection

Tags: email, checkbox, oracle-apex

I have created checkboxes in a report and I would like to be able to create a process that when multiple checkboxes are selected, an email is sent to the corresponding emails that was selected.

Comment: Which parts of this are you unfamiliar with? Just populating the 'To:' field or do you need help creating the email process itself?

Comment: I would like to do this http://cloudisfuture.blogspot.com/2012/05/sendemail-to-multiple-contacts-onclick.html, but in oracle apex

Comment: How did you add checkboxes: through the apex_item API? Have you taken a look at the apex_mail API? Is your page all set up and are you just trying to figure out how to process only checked records on page submit?

Comment: Hi Tom, yes i did, i used apex_item.checkbox. My page is already set up, i just need to know how to create the process to email only checked records